# struts2，Could not execute action: /newAction There is no Action mapped for action name newAction. - [unknown location]

Tags: java, struts2

> struts2，Could not execute action: /newAction  There is no Action mapped for action name newAction. - [unknown location]

Directory and error information

[image: Directory and error information]

Files are as follows, I do not know why it will be like that. Please, I am almost mad.

```
<%--new.jsp--%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>new.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
new
<s:action name="newAction"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<%-- a.jsp--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
a
</body>
</html>
```

```
<%!--struts2.xml--%>
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
  <package name="homework6" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="newAction" class="homework6.action.NewAction">
      <result name="success">/a.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

```
//NewAction
package homework6.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class NewAction extends ActionSupport {
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>default</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>new.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>a.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: struts2.xml?. Can you check your file for newAction is in struts.xml or struts2.xml? Could it be maybe you write in wrong file?. It suppose to be struts.xml.

Answer (score 0):

See the [struts.xml section](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html#step-6---create-strutsxml) of the "Getting Started" docs.

The default name of the Struts 2 configuration file is `struts.xml`.